# What is the config file for the sh shell on OS X? (i.e., ~/.bash_profile for bash shell, etc)

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, osx-mavericks

`R` uses the `/bin/sh` shell environment and I'm running scripts (that cannot be modified) that call `gfortran-4.8` instead of `gfortran` so I'm creating an `alias`.
I have added the following line to my `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`:
`alias gfortran-4.8='gfortran'`

However, here is the output from Terminal upon calling the alias `gfortran-4.8`:

```
my-MBP:~ myusername$ sh
sh-3.2$ gfortran-4.8 --version
sh: gfortran-4.8: command not found
```

Calling `gfortran` works just fine:

```
sh-3.2$ gfortran --version
gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.4.0
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

If not `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, where should the `alias` command go?

EDIT: Also tried adding the alias to `~/.bashrc` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What is your login or your interactive shell? (perhaps find out with `ps $$`) If it is `bash`  edit `~/.bashrc`

Comment: `ps $$` outputs `bash`, and I tried editing `~/.bashrc` but that didn't work either

Comment: **Edit your question** to improve it. Don't comment it.

Comment: 1) add the alias to `~/.bashrc` 2) enablt it with `source ~/.bashrc` 3) try calling the alias

Comment: Is there any way to include that on `sh` shell startup? While that works in Terminal it does not work in `R` even after executing `system('source ~/.bashrc')`. `R` by default requires the `sh` shell.

Comment: Using the `R` program and being limited to `sh` are key prerequisites for your problem and those must have been mentioned in the first row in the description.

Comment: You should probably consider checking some `.rprofile` configurations/customizations, like e.g. [this one](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start bash with as `sh` (for example, if `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `bash`), then the shell will only read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. The shell **will not** read `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Search for the phrase "invoked with the name sh" in your bash man page.

Answer (score 1):

When bash is invoked as `*/sh`, only `/etc/profile` and `${HOME}/.profile` are read.

I have these lines in my `.profile` (using OS X):

```
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    # include ~/.bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "${HOME}/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

My `.bashrc` contains (among other things) these lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Now just create a `.bash_aliases` file with all your aliases in it.

Answer (score 0):

it's usually simpler to just put all aliases and customizations to the shell into `~/.bashrc` and then have your `~/.bash_profile` source that file in it i.e. `source .bashrc` but if you make alias changes in your `~/.bashrc` they will not take affect until you reload your shell or source you're `~/.bashrc` file.